# AWS load balancer for Mean stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am learning load balancer and I have 2 instances connected to my load balancer but I always get out of service error.
Node is running in port 3000

my port configuration: 80 (HTTP) forwarding to 80 (HTTP)
health check: HTTP:3000/

My health check

[image]

Comment: Is Node listening to http on port 3000?

Comment: Check the instance security GRP. Does it allow traffic in 3000

Comment: Yes node is running on 3000. and yes 3000 is present in security group

Answer (score 0):

When you use "HTTP" ping protocol you have to upload a test file at the path "/" you cannot just use "/" in the path field.
Use the below setting and it will work.[image]

Comment: I did make changes but still out of service

Comment: Increase response time out and interval to 10 Sec. And remove the instance from load balancer and reattach it back.